# How to eliminate some rows and columns from a CSV file and save to new CSV?

Tags: vb.net

I have a csv file, where the first 3 rows have unwanted data. The 4th row has needed data in the first column only. There are 4 more rows with unwanted data. Rows 9 through the end have needed data.  Starting with row 9 there are 11 columns of data, columns 1 through 6 are needed, columns 7 through 11 are unwanted. 
I have code that uses a DataGridView for temporary storage. It provides the parsing described above, however I don't need to view the data, I need to create a new CSV file resulting from the parsing.
There is probably a method using a data table for temporary storage, instead of the DataGridView, however maybe there is a simpler way using LINQ. I have no experience with LINQ and my experience with data tables is very limited. I am very comfortable with DataGridView since I use it extensively, but as I wrote earlier I don't need to display the result.

I tried the code in:  https://www.codeproject.com/questions/634373/how-to-delete-the-rows-in-csv-file. But it doesn't fit my situation. The code below works using a DataGridView for temporary storage but I am sure there is a better way.

```
   Using MyReader As New TextFieldParser(racerFile)
        Dim currentRow As String()
        MyReader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {","}
        currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
        currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
        currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
        boatClass = MyReader.ReadFields()(0)
        currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
        currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
        currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
        currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                Dgvs.Rows.Add()
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                Dgvs(0, rd).Value = boatClass
                Dgvs(1, rd).Value = currentRow(1)
                Dgvs(2, rd).Value = currentRow(2)
                Dgvs(3, rd).Value = currentRow(3)
                Dgvs(4, rd).Value = currentRow(4)
                Dgvs(5, rd).Value = currentRow(5)
                rd += 1
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End While
   End Using

   Using WriteFile As New StreamWriter(myFile)
        For x As Integer = 0 To Dgvs.Rows.Count - 1 
            For y As Integer = 0 To Dgvs.Columns.Count - 1
                WriteFile.Write(Dgvs.Rows(x).Cells(y).Value)  
                If y <> Dgvs.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                    WriteFile.Write(", ")
                End If
            Next
            WriteFile.WriteLine()
        Next
    End Using
```

I need a CSV file for output.

Comment: Delete it or don't save it or don't read it. It should not appear in the finished CSV file. If you read the code above you see that rows 1-3 and 4-8 are read but not added to the DGV and are therefore not saved in the file created by the writing from the DGV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing values in a DatGridView, you could store them in a `List(Of String)`, where each string in the list is a line of the output csv file.

```
 Dim output As New List(Of String)
 While Not MyReader.EndOfData
     Try
         currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
         Dim line As String
         line = boatClass
         line = line & "," & currentRow(1).ToString
         line = line & "," & currentRow(2).ToString
         line = line & "," & currentRow(3).ToString
         line = line & "," & currentRow(4).ToString
         line = line & "," & currentRow(5).ToString
         output.Add(line)
     Catch ex As Exception
     End Try
 End While
```

And then you write `output` lines as follows.

```
Using WriteFile As New StreamWriter(myFile)
    For Each line As String In output 
        WriteFile.Write(line)
    Next
End Using
```

Comment: I haven't tried your code, but I am sure it works.  It is nice and clean. I like it. Thanks a lot.